# Iterating through an lazy load array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm tryin to build an array of hashes and then iterate through.
If I use the code below

```
    @elements = [{:profile_id=>"123"}, {:profile_id=>"456"}]
    @categories = Array.new
    @elements.each do |element|
     category = Category.find_by_profile_id(element[:profile_id])
     @categories.push(category)
    end
```

It will find the last object and it will add to the array. However I would like to fetch all the records with that id.

I have been trying the code bellow

```
    @elements = [{:profile_id=>"123"}, {:profile_id=>"456"}]
    @categories = Array.new
    @elements.each do |element|
     category = RootCategory.where(profile_id: element[:profile_id])
     @categories.push(category)
    end


 #response
 [#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Category id: "123", ...">, #<Category id: "123", ..."> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Category id: "456", ...">, #<Category id: "456", ...">]>]
```

I can't iterate through the returned array. If I try

```
@categories.each do |t|
   puts t.name
end

#Prints
#Category
#Category
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ avoid creating instance variables unless it’s really needed. Use local variables instead. E. g. `@elements` → `elements`. Do not pollute a global instance scope without a necessity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is mostly because you are abusing `each` for `map`ping. `ActiveRecord::Base#where` returns a `Relation` object (without a loss of generality it might be considered an array here). What you need is [`Enumerable#flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```
elements = [{:profile_id=>"123"}, {:profile_id=>"456"}]
@categories = 
  elements.flat_map do |element|
    RootCategory.where(profile_id: element[:profile_id])
  end
```

or, even better, avoid multiple queries, since `where` happily accepts an array:

```
@categories = 
  RootCategory.where(profile_id: elements.map { |e| e[:profile_id] })
```

The latter is basically executing:

```
RootCategory.where(profile_id: [123, 456])
```

retrieving categories for all the profiles specified.

Comment: You're just too fast!

Comment: @jvillian sorry for that :)